# DIV Filling Remaining Width of Container Which has Width 100%

Tags: html, css, layout

I've been searching all morning and I can't find a solution to my specific problem.  I have a layout where I have a left column that is set to about 50px and a right column that is set to take up the remaining 100% of the page.  This part works.

Now, in the right column, I have another 2 column layout.  But since the container's width is 100%, my inner right column keeps expanding past it's parent.  I need it to simply fill the remaining space, similar to the parent layout.  I've created a jsFiddle with my example code.

http://jsfiddle.net/87nb2/1/

As you can see, the green 'gallery' section is going past the right side of it's parent.  This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it at the moment, I think all you need to do is:

- On `#gallery`, change `width: 100%` to `right: 0`.
- This works because an element can have both `left` and `right` properties at the same time.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/87nb2/2/)

---

You might also want to adjust the `left` value to `50px`, to avoid cutting off some of the left element:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/87nb2/6/)

Comment: YES! Setting right: 0 solves the problem.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/87nb2/14/

```
#filmstrip_nav {
    float:left;
    height: 94%;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:red;
}

#gallery {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 94%;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%
    float:left;
}
```